# AngularJs escape bracket in name tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

There is a Rails Project, a form for user login with devise, but there is problem while use ng-show

```
  <%= f.email_field :email,class: "form-control", autofocus: true, placeholder: "input your email",required: true,"ng-model"=> "user[email]" %>
</div>
      <div style="color:red;" ng-show="myForm.user[email].$dirty && myForm.user[email].$invalid">
        <p ng-show="myForm.user[email].$error.required" style="float: left">email can't be blank</p>
        <p ng-show="myForm.user[email].$error.email" style="float: left">email is not correct</p>
      </div>
```

**myForm.user[email]** seems can't get object property, How can we make this line work without change input's name.

```
ng-show="myForm.user[email].$error.required"
```

In the other words,how can we escape`[]`

Comment: Are you sure it has to be `[email]` and not `.email`? Is `email` really a variable?

Comment: Yes, tag name is got from framework by default

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems with the Bracket notation inside Angular. See example below.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myForm = {};
  $scope.myForm.user1 = {};
  $scope.myForm.user2 = {};
  $scope.myForm.user1.email = {};
  $scope.myForm.user1.email.error = {};
  $scope.myForm.user1.email.error.required = {};
  $scope.myForm.user2.email = {};
  $scope.myForm.user2.email.error = {};
  $scope.myForm.user2.email.error.required = {};

  $scope.myForm.user1.email.error.required = false;
  $scope.myForm.user2.email.error.required = true;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-show="myForm['user2'].email.error.required">div1</div>
  <div ng-show="myForm['user1'].email.error.required">div2</div>


{{myForm.user1.email.error.required}} {{myForm.user2.email.error.required}} {{myForm['user1'].email.error.required}} {{myForm['user2'].email.error.required}}
</div>
```